# Тире или слеши?

Tags: выбор-слов, тире, косая-черта

«...О старте работ по капитальному ремонту улиц Караимская — Кавказская — Пролетарская». Стоит писать тире между улицами? Так как это участки улиц, которые примыкают к Пролетарской. Или слеши?

Comment: Так тире (как в шапке) или дефисы (как в предложении), *flossyU*? Вы уж определитесь.

Comment: Корректно, вместо *капремонта*, употребить «реконструкция». Улица — объект линейный.